# Unable to access Perforce files in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, perforce

How do I set up P4 Plugin in Jenkins so I can access the depot files?

I am trying to use the Jenkins P4 Plugin to manage Perforce and access shared libraries for Jenkins.  Whenever I try to sync a workspace, whether for using shared libraries or calling the `p4sync` step, the build fails.

Both these cases spit this into the console output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.client.ConnectionConfig.<init>(ConnectionConfig.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.client.ConnectionHelper.<init>(ConnectionHelper.java:105)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.client.ClientHelper.<init>(ClientHelper.java:107)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.tasks.AbstractTask.getConnection(AbstractTask.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.tasks.AbstractTask.setWorkspace(AbstractTask.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.PerforceScm.checkout(PerforceScm.java:429)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
```

My credentials point to the right user and P4PORT, and the SSL connection is good.

What do I need to do to get the P4 Plugin to sync properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins threw this error because it could not read the credentials.

For pipeline jobs to be able to use credentials, the credentials' *Scope* must be set to *Global*, not *Local*.  Since my Perforce credentials were set to *Local*, the pipeline job couldn't access them to pull the shared libraries or sync a workspace.

To change the *Scope* of the credentials, go to **Credentials** in the sidebar, select the credentials to change, click **Update**, and choose *Global* from the *Scope* dropdown.